# How to convert image path into content in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an image path link,
File: '/data/user/0/com.example.money_manager/cache/scaled_a375a605-34de-45cc-8bf9-20f893fcf0ec5338719552153510424.jpg'

How to convert this file path into the content path in dart.

Comment: what do you mean by "content path"?

Comment: I want to store images in the database using API. so that I want to convert images into connent.

Comment: Do you want an image URL instead image file path?

Comment: I want to store the image in the database using python API. I use an image picker to capture image and store the capture image path. I need a how-to store the image using API.

Comment: then you need to upload the local image to AWS or Cloudinary then you get a URL then you can use that URL for storing in the database.